# Using Typus with a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, typus

I'm trying to use the [Typus Rails Admin](https://github.com/fesplugas/typus) with a subdomain for a project. After installing Typus, and setting `config.subdomain = "admin"`, I noticed that the Typus-related routes get processed *after* the normal project routes.

When I visit `admin.mysite.com`, it goes to my main controller instead of Typus. I have to go to `admin.mysite.com/dashboard`. This is because the main application routes have higher priority over the Typus routes.

What I'd like is to have all routes with the `admin` subdomain processed by Typus, before processing the rest of the application routes. Is this possible with the Typus routing system?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already configure the subdomains option?

This is located in the config/initializers/typus.rb. The default setting is nil.

Typus.setup do |config| 
  config.subdomain = "admin" 
end

EDIT:

Here's a potential look for your routes file. Make sure that it's high enough up so it's processed before it matches with something else.

in your routes.rb

constraints :subdomain => "admin" do 
    controller :typus do 
      get "/admin", :action=>:index
    end 
  end

Comment: Hi Jeff, yep I'm doing that, just clarified the question

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me just comment on the question to ask that... I guess I don't have enough Rep. I'm editing my answer. I'm not very familiar with Typus but configuring the subdomain should work the same.